# Agregar un item de un spinner dentro de una tabla y mostrar informacion de spinners dependiendo de uno antes seleccionado

Tags: java, android, spinner

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Que tal muchachos, espero que me puedan ayudar, tengo 3 spinners y quiero que la informacion que muestre el spinner 3 dependa del spinner 2 y el spinner 2 dependa del spinner uno.

Luego de selecciona el tercer spinner, hacer click en el boton y agregarla informacion en una tabla, y continuar seleccionando y agregando sin que se pierda la información agregada en la tabla.

Necesito su ayuda muchachos por favor.

Comment: Tienes realizadas tus metodos dao para guardar los valores? sería buena idea los agregaras.

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar necesitas un listener para cada spinner. Dentro del listener obtenes el item seleccionado y lo utilizas para rellenar el segundo spinner, y asi sucesivamente.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
{
    String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();  
//this is your selected item
}
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
{

}           
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio un monton para darme una idea de que es lo que me falta, ese tipo de spinneres que necesite se llaman spinners dinamicos, ademas me apoye de esta pagina espero que les pueda servir, suerte muchachos. [https://amatellanes.wordpress.com/2013/09/09/android-spinner-dinamico-en-android-provincias-y-localidades-de-espana/]

Comment: Me alegro, si te sirvió lo suficiente podrias marcar la respuesta como aceptada. saludos